# I cant seem to find the error behind this code I am trying to fix in c#, it uses a few classes separated by the hashtag symbol

Tags: c#

I am trying to have the code post a sentence relating to breakfast, but can't find the problem.
in the public partial class debug_5 : form at the bottom there is a error in the text lblTodaysSpecial = ("Today we have {1} for {2}", special.Name, special.Price.ToString("C2"));. And I cant find out exactly what the problem is with the statement. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Debug_5
{
    class Breakfast
    {
        public static string INFO = "Breakfast is the most important meal of the day.";
        private string name;
        private decimal price;
        // Breakfast constructor requires a
        // name, e.g "French toast", and a price
        public Breakfast(string name, double price)
        {
            Name = name;
            Price = price;
        }
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public double Price{get; set;}
    }
}
#####################
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Debug_5
{
    public partial class Debug5: Form
    {
        Breakfast special;
        public Debug5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            special = Breakfast("French Toast", 4.99);
            lblInfoMessage.Text = Breakfast.INFO;
        }

        private void btnShowSpecial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblTodaysSpecial = ("Today we have {1} for {2}", special.Name, special.Price.ToString("C2"));
        }
    }
}
##########################
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Debug_5
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Debug5());
        }
    }
}'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `String.Format` and to access `.Text` as well as starting index from 0

```cs
lblTodaysSpecial.Text = string.Format("Today we have {0} for {1}", special.Name, special.Price.ToString("C2"));
```

Comment: As a bit of an extra, it should be possible to use the format for `Price` in the string directly like so: `string.Format("Today we have {0} for {1:C2}", special.Name, special.Price);`

Answer (score 0):

Jack is correct, he beat me...

But, you can also do this if your goal was to avoid typing `string.Format`:

`var lblTodaysSpecial = $"Today we have {special.Name} for {special.Price:C2}";`

This is called "string interpolation", available in C# 6.0+ I think.